# vertical align links and logo in nav bar

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm having trouble vertically aligning the links and the logo inside the list any idea what i can to fix it?
Here is the code in codepen.
http://codepen.io/tacoxlegendary/pen/VjXqkA?editors=1100

```
<body>
<nav>
    <div class="wrapper ">

        <ul class="cf">
            <li id="logo">LOGO</li>

            <li>SIGN IN</li>
            <li>LOCTION</li>
            <li>TEAM</li>
            <li>ABOUT</li>
        </ul>
    </div> <!-- wrapper end -->
</nav>
```

```
.wrapper {
max-width: 1120px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
nav {
  background-color: #F7FDFE;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #45494D;
  float: right;
  padding: 10px; 
  font-size: 14px;
}
nav ul #logo {
  float: left;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

Comment: what you expect exactly..?

Comment: Could you clearify how it should look like?

Comment: Can you draw your required layout and post? (possibly in paint)

Answer (score 0):

Add `padding:0` to `nav ul #logo`

```css
.wrapper {
max-width: 1120px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
nav {
  background-color: #F7FDFE;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #45494D;
  float: right;
  padding: 10px; 
  font-size: 14px;
}
nav ul #logo {
  float: left;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div class="wrapper ">

        <ul class="cf">
            <li id="logo">LOGO</li>

            <li>SIGN IN</li>
            <li>LOCTION</li>
            <li>TEAM</li>
            <li>ABOUT</li>
        </ul>
    </div> <!-- wrapper end -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple way to center the navbar and logo in the center of navbar is to set a height to navbar and give the same value as line-height to li 
like

```
nav {
 height: 70px;
}
ul.cf {
line-height: 70px;
}
```